# When will RTMP client initiate the operation of deletestream()

Tags: rtmp

I'm a beginner of RTMP. I have a question. I see that the RTMP client will initiate the operation of **deletestream**. Under what circumstances will the client initiate this operation?

This message comes from Wireshark:

```
37  0.400350    172.17.4.58 192.168.11.240  RTMP    411 @setDataFrame()|Video Data|FCUnpublish()|deleteStream()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been solved, the server sends the FIN package to disconnect, and the client will execute **deletestrem** operation after the TCP connection is disconnected.